# Multiple Rows into single row in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I m having datas as like below

```
Ins_Ind   Dns_IND  Mns_IND  Fns_IND
  1          1       0        0
  0          0       1        0
  0          1       0        0   

Expected Result:
Ins_Ind   Dns_IND  Mns_IND  Fns_IND
  1          1       1        0
```

Multiple rows into single row

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to query the maximum of each column:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Ins_Ind), MAX(Dns_IND), MAX(Mns_IND), MAX(Fns_IND)
FROM   mytable
```